# Can React.useEffect handle an async EffectCallback return?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect

I have a component which must unsubscribe to something asynchronously. Is this possible with `React.useEffect`?

e.g.:

```
useEffect(() => {
  doSomething();
  return () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      myThing.unsubscribe().then(() => { resolve(); })
    })
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. What's the purpose? You can do async operation there, as long as you don't update the state of unmounted comp although there could be better ways to achieve this.

Comment: @EstusFlask Well, the unsubscribe function itself is an async removeEventListener sort of function, but you may be right that it doesn’t matter if it finishes.. unless I were to need to resubscribe again

Comment: @EstusFlask I’m using the npm broadcast-channel .close() function at the top level of the app, and I’ve noticed the test runner is probably complaining about this

Comment: Depends on your case. In case the problem is specific to tests, you may want to spy on unsubscribe and chain a promise it returns in afterEach, or else.